# JQuery Datepicker : Month and Year repopulating

Tags: styles

This is my code

1.Click the datepicker and change month or year.

2.Now input field modified.

3.Close the datepicker and again click the datepicker modified value not setted in datepicker.

Please help this issue.

```
$( "#monthYearOnly" ).datepicker({
  buttonImage: "../images/calendar.png",
  buttonImageOnly: true,
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true,
  showOn: "both",
  dateFormat: 'yy/mm',
  maxDate : '0d',
  defaultDate: '1d',
  constrainInput: false,
  buttonText: 'Click to show the month',
  onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
    var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
    var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
    $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
  }
});

$("#monthYearOnly").focus(function (year, month, inst) {
  var test = $("#monthYearOnly").val();
  $(".ui-datepicker-calendar").hide();
  $("#ui-datepicker-div").position({
    my: "center top",
    at: "center bottom",
    of: $(this)
  });
});
});
```

I am using three three datepicker in single jsp page

Two datepicker with calendar and another one without calendar(only month and year)

Comment: FYI, you seem to have an extra `})` in there.

Answer (score 0):

You can introduce a `beforeShow`.
Your datepicker can look as follows:

```
$("#monthYearOnly").datepicker({
    buttonImage: "../images/calendar.png",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showOn: "both",
    dateFormat: 'yy/mm',
    maxDate: '0d',
    defaultDate: '1d',
    constrainInput: false,
    buttonText: 'Click to show the month',

    onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
        var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
        var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();

        $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
    },

    beforeShow: function() {
      var dateText = $(this).val();
      var isPopulated = dateText.length > 0;

      if (isPopulated) {
        var selectedDate = $.datepicker.parseDate("yy/mm/dd", dateText + "/01");

        $(this).datepicker("option", "defaultDate", selectedDate);
        $(this).datepicker("setDate", selectedDate);
        $(this).datepicker("refresh");
      }
    },

});
```

I believe this will get you what you are trying to achieve.